# Numerically solve for limit of integration using Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to solve for the upper limit of integration:

```
def integrand(t):
    return (Dou)*np.exp((-Eau)/(8.314*(996.74 + (1037.1*np.exp(-0.2696*t)))))

def func(x):
    y, err=quad(integrand, 0, x)
    return y

sol = fsolve(func, 1.0)

print(sol[b])
```

Where Dou, Eau, and b are randomly defined variables.

I want to solve for the upper limit of integration such that the integral is equal to b. I can't figure out what is wrong with this code -- any glaringly obvious errors?

Comment: Does it throw an error or produce the wrong result?

Answer (score -1):

The method `fsolve` finds a root of equation func = 0. If your equation has right hand side `b` instead of 0, subtract that `b` from the output of `func`.

To make a self-contained example, I'll put it a numeric value for b, as well as for other undefined constants in your code.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si 
import scipy.optimize as so

def integrand(t):
    return 3*np.exp((-2)/(8.314*(996.74 + (1037.1*np.exp(-0.2696*t)))))

def func(x):
    return si.quad(integrand, 0, x)[0] - 7    # func is integral minus 7

sol = so.fsolve(func, 1.0)                    # equated func to 0
print(sol)
```